# Problem Migrating Rails 3.0.9 to Rails 3.1? ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following [chapter 2 of ruby.railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#top) and haven't able to connect to the DB on Rails 3.1.

My guess is some gem in the Gemfile is missing.

I've tried using the provided Gemfile (to no avail, localhost doesn't even reach the server) and the default one. The default one gets me this:

[image]

How can I setup this Gemfile correctly for Rails 3.1?

Comment: Is sqlite3 already installed and running properly?

Comment: @JW: it isn't, I ran gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter and got this: Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository

Comment: I solved the issue changing the version of sqlite in the Gemfile to sqlite 1.3.4 :)

Comment: Nice, glad to hear that it's working for you now.

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me as well. Make sure you are running the latest sqlite3 gem.

In your `Gemfile`, relax the dependency to `~> 1.3.0`, then update the `Gemfile.lock` by running

```
$ bundle update sqlite3
```